# How do you Open a "Task Manager" (as in Chrome) in Safari?

Tags: google-chrome, memory, browser, safari

I assumed that since both browsers are based on WebKit, that this feature would crossover, or whatnot...  I guess I'm wondering **if any of the Google Chrome "nerd" stuff, especially the "task manager" is available for Safari..** either natively, or via extensions??

[image: menu in chrome]
[image: chrome task manager]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

WebKit is just the rendering engine - you could use Activity Viewer or top to see Safari's activity.

IIRC though Chrome renders every window/tab as its own process; Safari does sandbox plug-ins but not individual pages.

Answer (score 4):

In Activity Monitor, you can mouse over the safari tasks and it will pop-up which URLs are on that task.